# How to check in Scala if a specific function returns empty?

Tags: scala

I have this function:

`type CustomSet = Int => Boolean`

If I want to make the intersection I do something like:

```
def intersection(s: CustomSet, t: CustomSet): CustomSet = {
        (x: Int) => contains(s, x) && contains(t, x)
  }
```

Now, I don't see any way to check if intersection of two sets is empty...

I tried a lot of ways:

`-  if (intersection(s, t) == CustomSet())`

`-  if (intersection(s, t) == None)`

etc but it's not working...

Can you please tell me where I am wrong in this checking?

Comment: `CustomSet` is itself just a *function*. Not the most useful structure here as the `intersection` doesn't return the intersection, but rather returns a new "set" that only "contains" `x` if both `s` and `t` "contained" `x`. (Function objects are generally not comparable in any meaningful fashion aside from identity.)

Comment: Why not check for `intersection(s, t)` size? E.g. `isEmpty` or `.size == 0`?

Comment: @om-nom-nom Because there is none, and hence the problem with this "set" intersection :)

Comment: The problem can not be solved elegantly. You have to do a brute-force: Check all elements of a given range (maybe from -100 to 100) if they, applied to `contains`, evaluate to false. If yes, the set is probably empty.

Comment: `==` is not specifically defined for `Function`s: it's just reference equality, so your `CustomSet` instances won't ever be equal to anything but themselves. To explain the other terms you've misused: `CustomSet()` would refer to the `apply` method of some `CustomSet` object which I assume you haven't defined. These are set up as factory methods for most collections. `None` is one of the possible values of an `Option`, which is not relevant since a Function is not an Option.

Comment: @sschaef Thanks, indeed your solution is the way I had to go for my issue...

Comment: Even If this question is from a Coursera assignment I don't see why it's score is negative.

Answer (score 2):

Just putting all the comments together:

The result of `intersection` is just a function. You can compare two functions for referential equality, i.e. if they are one and the same function.

There is no way to test if two functions return the same result (and have the same side effects) for all possible parameters (and system states), so all you can do is define a range of input parameters you care about and compare the results of two functions with all the results for all the interesting input parameters.

So in your case you could do something like

```
(-1000 to 1000).forall(!intersection(s,t)(_))
```

which would test if all the numbers from -1000 to 1000 are Not in the intersection of `s` and `t`